# Mount a CIFS share on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS as guest

Tags: mount, fstab, cifs

I have searched and found many things but nothing is working.
I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
I can mount a remote CIFS share using user and password ok. using `mount //IP.Address/Share /mnt/path -t cifs -o user=username,pass=password`

But I have another 3 shares that are simple NAS shares (Freenas) and there is no password, guest access only.
trying `mount //IP.Address/Share/Path /mnt/path2 -t cifs -o guest`

just dumps mount options.

I cannot get the non password protected shares to mount.
cifs utils is obviously installed.
My aim is to be able to mount these all in fstab.

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you pass it a password that it does not need?

Comment: I have tried passing guest,options and even using user=root,pass=passwd. it returns: mount error(95): Operation not supported
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Comment: I just managed to get this to work. NAS (freenas) configured to use SMB v3.0 as minimum protocol, changed this to ver 2.0 and used the following command to mount: //10.100.100.10/Public/Media /mnt/media cifs guest,vers=3.0,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,_netdev 0 0 , note the vers=3.0 and sec=ntlm options.